# I can not add value to the cache? Yii framework

Tags: php, caching, yii

I have this code:

```
$success = Yii::$app->cache->set($cacheKey, $data, DAY, $this->dependency);
```

where:

```
$cacheKey = "Images::/2ws/dsasdsadas/",
$data = {simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom_node}[23]
DAY = 86400
$this->dependency = {yii\caching\DbDependency}[6]
```

In config file, used:

'components.cache_db' => [
    'class' => \yii\caching\FileCache::className(),

The situation is this, does not add value to the cache, $success, returns false. 
What could be the problem, as it is to diagnose and treat?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was access to a folder on the 775 replaced the 777.